# Manually create a computed property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here is the problem. I'm currently creating a mixin to handle form validation. The problem is that I want to create in the init method a computed property `isFormValid` which is a `'computed.and'` property of the `'is<fieldName>Valid'` other properties.

I can create it but then it never updates. I guess I need to add observers but maybe someone will have a better solution ?

**EDIT**
Here is some clarification.

My controller got that property:

```
App.FormViewController = Ember.Controller.extend(App.ValidatorMixin, {
    validations: {
        field1: {
            errLvl: App.Validation.ErrLvl.ERROR,
            type: App.Validation.Type.TEXT,
            pattern: /^\d{6}$/,
            message: 'Error message'
        },
        field2: {
            //somecode
        }
    }
});
```

The mixin is define as follow:

```
App.ValidatorMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    init: function() {
        this._super();

        var self = this;
        Ember.keys(this.validations).forEach(function(prop) {
            self.set('is' + prop.capitalize() + 'Valid', false); //Is changed when the field is valid
        });
    }
});
```

The `isFormValid` property should be an `Ember.computed.and` of all these `is<fieldName>Valid`

**EDIT2**
Every input on the form are defined by the input helper and this mixin:

```
App.Mixin.ValidatableInput = Ember.Mixin.create({
    focusOut: function() {
        this.validate();
    },
    //Do the validation
    validate: function() {
        //I'm currently moving that part to the controller because it's part
        //of the logic but it was easier for a start to write it here

        //We update the is<fieldName>Valid property
        this.get('parentView.controller').set('is' + this.get('name').capitalize() + 'Valid', !hasError);

        //Then some DOM manipulation to attach the error message
    }
});
```

And finally my view looks like that

```
{{view App.CustomTextField name="field1" value=field1}}
{{view view.buttonCreate disabled=isFormInvalid}}
```

Answer (score 0):

From within your `init` method you can setup a computed property using `defineProperty`.

```
Ember.defineProperty(myObject, 'myProperty', Ember.computed(function computed() {

    return 'myValue';

}).property('myObserver'));
```

Comment: I can't do such thing because the ```myObserver``` is an array of dynamically generated values.
I could also do ```this.set('isFormValid', Ember.computed(...).property())``` which set it for the first time but then don't update when the dependent keys are updated.

Comment: Then how about `myObserver.length` so it will fire each time the array is updated? You also have `myObserver.@each` which would do largely the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work because I don't update the array but the properties referenced by the array.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? (expanding off @Wildhoney, I can't comment). You can specify multiple properties if you have several:

```
Ember.defineProperty(myObject, 'myProperty', Ember.computed(function computed() {

    return 'myValue';

}).property('myObserver.@each.myObservedProperty'));
```

I've had a bit of luck using jQuery Validate in Ember by triggering the .validate() call and rules on didInsertElement for your form view, and then a .valid() check when you focus out of each Ember.TextField. I would highly recommend it for form validation.